# Libgdx Character Run Animation not Showing

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx

My `movement animation` is not playing. My characters still pose show but when moving it stays in that static position. The `animation loop` doesn't seem to play.

My code is as below:

```
public class Char extends Sprite {

  public enum State {   STANDING, RUNNING };
  public State currentState;
  public State previousState;
  TextureRegion region;
  private TextureRegion Still;
  private Animation Go;

  private float stateTimer;

  public World world;
  public Body b2body;

  public Char(World world, PlayScreen screen){
    super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("NewRun"));

    currentState = State.STANDING;
    previousState = State.STANDING;
    stateTimer = 0;

    Array<TextureRegion> frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();

    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
      frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(),i* 53,0,53,48));
    Go = new Animation(0.1f, frames);

    frames.clear();

    Still = new TextureRegion(getTexture(),0,0,53,50);
    setBounds(0, 0, 50 / Game.PPM, 65 / Game.PPM);
    setRegion(Still);
    this.world = world;
    defineChar();
  }

  public void update(float dt) {
    setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
    setRegion(getFrame(dt));
  }

  public TextureRegion getFrame(float dt) {
    currentState = getState();
    switch(currentState){
      case RUNNING:
        Go.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
        break;
      case STANDING:
      default:
        region = Still;
        break;
    }

    stateTimer = currentState == previousState ? stateTimer + dt : 0;
    //update previous state
    previousState = currentState;
    //return our final adjusted frame
    return region;
  }

  public void defineChar(){
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(50/ JoD.PPM, 20/ JoD.PPM);
    bdef.type =BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2body = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

    CircleShape shape =new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(4);

    fdef.shape= shape;
    b2body.createFixture(fdef);//.setUserData(this);
  }

  public State getState(){
    if(b2body.getLinearVelocity().x != 0)
      return State.RUNNING;
    //if none of these return then he must be standing
    else
     return State.STANDING;
  }

}
```

I've looked into multiple tutorials but can't see why the animation is not playing through.
Can anyone see what I have missed?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the Sprite is receiving update events? Is you explicitly set the state to RUNNING, does the animation work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you missing the assignment to region inside your getFrame(float dt) method? The region you draw is always "Still"??

```
switch(currentState){
      case RUNNING:
        //Go.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
        //Should be ...
        region = Go.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
        break;
      case STANDING:
      default:
        region = Still;
        break;
    }
```